# Oracle dynamically framing pivot for multiple columns

Tags: oracle

I have the below table

[image: Item_no item_type measure_name measure_value measure_type 1001 SAR Area 1000 sqft 1001 SAR width 200 mm 1001 SAR breadth 230 cm 1002 SEN diameter 100 mm 1002 SEN height 20 mm 1003 ZPR length 100 mm 1003 ZPR width 200 mm 1003 ZPR height 100 cm]

How to get in below table format
[image: Item_no item_type Area_value Area_type width_measure_value width_type breadth_value breadth_type diameter_value diameter_type height_value height_type 1001 SAR 1000 sqft 200 mm 230 cm 1002 SEN null null null null null null 100 mm 20 mm]
.
.
.

Here item_no and item_name keeps growing with different measure_name,measure_value, measure_type..

How to dynamically frame multiple columns based on above measurements columns.

I am using oracle 19c.

Comment: Might be useful to reformat that question so we can understand what you're asking.  But this link might be useful https://technology.amis.nl/oracle/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/

Comment: Short answer is Oracle does not support dynamic pivots. You are better solving this problem in whatever client application you are using to access the database (C#, PHP, Java, etc.). If you really must attempt it in the database (don't) then you will either require dynamic SQL or to use something like an XML pivot (see the linked duplicate), but then you would have XML output and not columns.